# VBA - Passing value to a public class variable returns in "False" return

Tags: excel, vba, class

Possibly a rookie mistake:

I am trying to build a class in VBA with a function that allows me to give a name to an object. With the following code

```
' Class Module: AR (short for Analysis Result)
Public name As String

Public Sub initialise(sometext As String)
    name = sometext
End Sub
```

Rest of the work is done by a function, which generates the object an then passes a value to it.

```
Function ARTODSN()
    Dim Result As New AR
    
    Result.initialise (sometext = "your mama")
    
    ARTODSN = Result.name
End Function
```

I was hoping, that the function would return the name i passed into the initialise function.
However, the result of the function in my worksheet is always "False".

When I change the Sub initialise to the following, everything seems to work...

```
Public Sub initialise(sometext As String)
    name = "some text but inside the sub"
End Sub
```

Comment: `(sometext = "your mama")` returns `False` when evaluated - try it without the parenthesis. See how VBA added a space before the parenthesis? That's a hint.

Comment: Not quite, but it let me to the right solution. Thank your for the quick reply.

`sometext = "your mama"` always gets evaluated as a boolean...

i rewrote the function call to `Result.initialise "your mama"` and now it works.

Comment: With named argument `Result.initialise sometext := "your mama"`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use named parameter. In that case, the call would be

```
Result.initialise sometext := "your mama"
```

Alternative would be one of the two ways

```
Result.initialise "your mama"
Call Result.initialise("your mama")
```

But **don't use parenthesis** when *not* using `Call` - they have a different meaning.

```
Result.initialise ("your mama")
```

And this syntax is invalid anyhow, the compiler will complain:

```
Result.initialise (sometext := "your mama")
```

---

In your current code, you use (sometext = "your mama"). The VBA runtime will, *before* calling the `initialise` method, evaluate this term: It will compare the variable `sometext` with the string `"your mama"`, and that is either True or False.

Just a guess: You don't have a variable `sometext` in Sub `ARTODSN` and therefore VBA will create it on the fly. To prevent it, always use `Option Explicit`: In that case, the VBA compiler would complain about a missing variable declaration and you could see that there is something wrong with the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for you code as below, `sometext` is a named parameter. Using `:=` instead of `=`.

```
Result.initialise sometext:= "your mama"
```

---

Class modules enable OOP design. Avoid public module-scope variables, use proper encapsulation.

Please try.

```vb
' Class Module: AR (short for Analysis Result)
Private mName As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal sometext As String)
    mName = sometext
End Property
---
' Testing code
Function ARTODSN()
    Dim Result As New AR
    Result.Name = "your mama"
    ARTODSN = Result.Name
End Function

Sub demo()
    Debug.Print ARTODSN
End Sub
```

---

If you prefer to using `Initialise`

```
' Class Module: AR (short for Analysis Result)
Private mName As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal sometext As String)
    mName = sometext
End Property

Public Sub Initialise(ByVal sometext As String)
    mName = sometext
End Sub

---

' Testing code
Function ARTODSN1()
    Dim Result As New AR
    Result.Initialise "your papa"
    ARTODSN1 = Result.Name
End Function

Sub demo1()
    Debug.Print ARTODSN1
End Sub
```